# How to tidy this dataset so that there is one individual(ID) per row?

Tags: r

I am having a bit of trouble with this one (new to r). I want ID to be a single row per individual. Some individuals have more weight measurements than others (actually in the real example vary from 7 to NA).

1) How can I spread data so as to only have a single row per individual?

2) How can I show only the avg weight for each individual with >1 measurement)?

Many thanks

```
 ID  Weight   Year
1001   48     2014
1001   50     2015
1002   70     2014
1003   72     2012
1003   75     2015
1003   78     2007
1003   74     2003
```

Comment: Could you show the output you are trying to obtain?

Answer (score 1):

With tidyr:

```
d <- data.frame(ID = c(1001, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003),
                Weight = c(48, 50, 70, 72, 75, 78, 74),
                Year = c(2014, 2015, 2014, 2012, 2015, 2007, 2003))
library(tidyr)
d %>% 
    spread(Year, Weight)

    ID   2003 2007 2012 2014 2015
1 1001   NA   NA   NA   48   50
2 1002   NA   NA   NA   70   NA
3 1003   74   78   72   NA   75
```

@Floo0 provides a good option for calculating means with tidyr.

or with base:

```
reshape(d,
    idvar = "ID",
    v.names = "Weight",
    timevar = "Year",
    direction = "wide")

    ID Weight.2014 Weight.2015 Weight.2012 Weight.2007 Weight.2003
1 1001          48          50          NA          NA          NA
3 1002          70          NA          NA          NA          NA
4 1003          NA          75          72          78          74
```

And to calculate the means

```
aggregate(Weight ~ ID, data = d, FUN = mean)
    ID Weight
1 1001  49.00
2 1002  70.00    
3 1003  74.75
```

Comment: To take the mean after spreading, one can use `rowwise()` like so:
   
   ` d %>% spread(Year, Weight) %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(avg = mean(c(\`2003\`, \`2007\`, \`2014\`, \`2015\`), na.rm = T))`